# XML with XSLT Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform a simple XML document using the XSLT Transform, although when I try to run the XML on the browser [Chrome or Safari], I'm getting an error 'The document is empty', but the XML that I'm using is not empty.

Any hints where my error is and also how to solve it? much appreciated.

XML - people3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="people.xsl"?>

<people>
    <husband employee="Yes">
        <name>Mark</name>
        <age>45</age>
            <wife>
                <wname>Janet</wname>
                <age>29</age>
            </wife>
    </husband>
    <husband employee="No">
        <name>Matt</name>
        <age>42</age>
            <wife>
                <wname>Annie</wname>
                <age>41</age>
            </wife>
    </husband>
</people>
```

XSL - people.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xdl:stylesheet version='1.0'

xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="name">
    Hello from XSLT
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So what is the result format you expect from that code?

Comment: Why does the XSLT have `xdl:stylesheet` but declares `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"`? I guess you want `xsl:stylesheet`.

Comment: It's a good idea to test your stylesheets in an environment other than the browser, especially when you're a raw beginner. You get better diagnostics that way.

Comment: @MartinHonnen the outcome I was expecting was Hello from XSLT. Also I have a typo error during the upload of the file, yes it is xsl:stylesheet. Although having it on that way is not showing nothing yet.

Comment: @MichaelKay thank you, at the moment I'm just getting use to it with this kind of files. Any ideas about how to improve testing for XML and JSON files will be appreciated.

Comment: Show us the real code you have and explain exactly how you are trying to run/use the XSLT? Is that using an `xml-stylesheet` pi in the XML that you load in a browser window? From the file system or over HTTP(S)? Or are you using JavaScript? Then show us the exact JavaScript code. It would also help us if you explain whether that is your first attempt to use XSLT in the browser and other created the output you wanted but this particular stylesheet fails or whether that is your first stab at trying to use XSLT in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you are just running into a WebKit specific limitation of the type of result you can produce with XSLT in the browser, instead of just pushing some text out to the result as a fragment you should try to construct some HTML document so a minimal sample constructing a HTML result document and incorporating your template would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>

<xsl:template match="name">
    Hello from XSLT
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That way that message about an empty document should go away and some result would be rendered, not really a meaningful one as there are built-in templates that kick in to output any text nodes anyway and as your template matches two `name` elements in the input sample so the body of the constructed HTML will be like

```
Hello from XSLT

    45
        
            Janet
            29
        


    
Hello from XSLT

    42
        
            Annie
            41
```

It is not clear what output you want to achieve but keep in mind that you are better off in the browser to start with creating some more or less well-structured HTML document to be rendered than working with text fragments.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation and the examples! Much appreciated!